# Why Im not being able to filter this Array result from gql query?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuejs3, gql

To be honest I'm quite new with all these three technologies, vue, gql and typeScript, anyway the problem it's pretty simple. I'm using **useQuery** to fetch data and a computed prop to access the result.
I want to filter the 'clubs' based on their 'locationId' before returning to the  el but I just can't, trying things i created an interface which might be not a good option,  here's the code:

```
    const { result } = useQuery(
      gql`
        query getClubAndLocations {
          getLocations {
            _id
            name
          }
          getClubs {
            _id
            name
            locationID
          }
        }
      `
    )

    interface Club {
      _id: string
      name: string
      locationID: string
    }

    const clubOptions = computed<Club[]>(() => result.value?.getClubs ?? [])

    const filterOptions = computed(() => {
      return clubOptions.filter
    })
```

Here's the image:
[image]

The error says: `Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'ComputedRef<Club[]>'.ts(2339)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`computed()` returns a [`ref`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref), so you need to unwrap the value through its `.value` property:

```js
const filterOptions = computed(() => {
                       
  return clubOptions.value.filter
})
```

[demo](https://tsplay.dev/W4PA1W)